# Restore Apache derby In-memory database

Tags: database, derby, database-backups, database-restore, in-memory-database

I have created Backup of my in-memory database using the below code:

```
public static void backUpDatabase(Connection conn)throws SQLException
{
String backupdirectory ="c:/mybackups/"+JCalendar.getToday();
CallableStatement cs = conn.prepareCall("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_BACKUP_DATABASE(?)"); 
cs.setString(1, backupdirectory);
cs.execute(); 
cs.close();
System.out.println("backed up database to "+backupdirectory);
}
```

Now I want to restore the database by creating an In-memory database from the previous backup. How should I do it?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

The fastest way I am aware of:

First, use `shutdown=true`:

```
boolean gotSQLExc = false;
    try {
        DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;shutdown=true");
    } catch (SQLException se) {
        if ( se.getSQLState().equals("08006") )
            System.out.println("Database shut down normally");
        else
            System.out.println("Database did not shut down normally")
    }
```

Then `restoreFrom=`

```
    Connection connection = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby:memory:testdb;restoreFrom=path/to/backup/file");
    connection.close();
```

A db containing ~300 tables with some sample data restored in ~150ms on my dev machine this way.

This is really useful for junit integration testing where fast fast db restore is needed. Depending on your setup, you may need to perform some additional work in-between tests, for example if using c3p0 connection pool, you need to get all connections from C3P0Registry and call hardReset() after this restore. On the other hand, nothing needs to be done with some other pools.

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the normal restore-from-backup mechanisms will work just fine to restore an in-memory database. So use the restoreFrom clause on your connection URL, as described here: http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.9/adminguide/tadminhubbkup44.html